# Rest Client on Tomcat, Response time spikes every hour

Tags: performance, rest, tomcat, monitoring

I'm running a tomcat server which has an http REST client and makes requests to other servers. I'm measuring 2 request metrics, average time and the 95th percentile time. I notice that the 95th percentile time spikes every one hour. This is not seen on the servers which return the response.

Any idea how to detect the cause of these spikes?

Comment: I am seeing something similar in my app. Can you add more details? a) is it approx one hour not exact? b) are you using new relic? c) is the average response time on the server giving response ok but some calls taking time but somehow it's not reflecting in average? d) are you using cached thread pool? e) does spike in response time coincide with that thread count increase?